# How to hide chat icon in bot press?

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented bot press in my react web application.It works well.But,the problem is i want to close the bot press chat icon when user logout from my web app.If i manually refresh the page then the chat icon is not showing for me.But,i want solution for destroy bot press when user logout the web application strong text.Please reply me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear by I'm assuming you mean BotPress as in https://botpress.io? Also **i want solution for destroy bot press** what do you mean here or want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a state named `isLoggedIn` which is initially be `false` when user logged in it should set to `true`, and when user is logging out set that state to `false`, and render that bot press on condition if `isLoggedIn` state is `true`